# How to get coordinates from Google Maps share url on Android

Tags: android, url, maps

I'm trying to decode this url: https://www.google.com/maps/place//data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4745bd4af4e60a51:0xd62aba005d92953d?utm_source=mstt_1LM_pY9N8KOrk5pGERKQRIPXvuU12TY

I am guessing that "0x4745bd4af4e60a51:0xd62aba005d92953d" is the part storing the coordinates but I am not sure how to decode it. I tried to convert it from hex to decimal but it doesn't give me a coordinate value.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I have found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47075013) containing the exact answer to my question.

Both methods work:

1. Calling https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=YOUR_API_KEY&ftid=0xd62377123a70817:0x85e89b65fcf7c648 and extract coordinates from "geometry"
2. Converting "0x85e89b65fcf7c648" (second number, after colon) into decimal, resulting a CID number. Then, the location can be decoded by accessing https://google.com/maps?cid=16601872622479930233

Comment: Method 2: you convert the hex into decimal, and then what? you obtain a big int number, not a lat/lng coordinates. What do you do next? Thanks

Comment: @Gabriel, the returned number is a CID. You can access it like this: https://google.com/maps?cid=16601872622479930233

Comment: Thanks. But still, it does not contain any direct Lat Lng indication. You still have to use a browser to search for them in the HTML response.

Comment: @Gabriel, unfortunately yes

Answer (score 0):

The Coordinates are listed in UTM and not Lat/Long.   There are convertors online that will help with this conversion.   When you click on the link you will see the following URL: 
 https://www.google.com/maps/place/Westfield/@46.225795,21.2673783,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4745bd4af4e60a51:0xd62aba005d92953d!8m2!3d46.225795!4d21.269567.

The coordinates are listed as :  46.225795,21.2673783
You have a couple of options, 1) Download Google Earth and enter the coordinates in the search box.  From the tag you can retrieve the lat/long
2) Open Google maps and type those coordinates in and you will see the Lat/Long listed below that search box.

Comment: Google Earth or Google Maps is not helping me because I need to obtain the coordinates in my Android app.