# Incorrect coordinates in url of google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a short url of Google Maps like this: https://goo.gl/maps/vRnHE6yvKvnixpGb7, which when opening it, you get the full url like this: https://www.google.com/maps/place/Abarrotes+%22La+Escondida%22/@28.6839691,-106.1021991,196m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x86ea43ae490dc3cd:0xabf595a99559d5d5!8m2!3d28.6839087!4d-106.1027089?shorturl=1.

The problem is that if the link correctly positions the place, but the latitude and longitude are not exactly correct, it has a margin of error of certain meters. How can I solve this problem or get the coordinates?

I have only these short URLs and I need to get their coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates after the @ are the center of the map, not the location, that is at the end of the URL: `28.6839087!4d-106.1027089`
(28.6839087,-106.1027089)

[https://www.google.com/maps/place/28%C2%B041'02.1%22N+106%C2%B006'09.8%22W/@28.6839214,-106.1049109,526m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d28.6839087!4d-106.1027089](https://www.google.com/maps/place/28%C2%B041%2702.1%22N+106%C2%B006%2709.8%22W/@28.6839214,-106.1049109,526m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d28.6839087!4d-106.1027089)

[image: screenshot of map]

Related question: [Decoding the Google Maps embedded parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017387/decoding-the-google-maps-embedded-parameters)